# How to find all packages included in Microsoft.AspNetCore.App shared framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Is there an official list of all the assemblies in the Microsoft.AspNetCore.App shared framework? Which is referenced in .csproj's as:

```xml
<FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
```

All I could find is an old package list from January 2019 which no longer exists in the [aspnetcore](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore) repo:

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/da31275d4c03db4887293411cac76bd987e63548/src/Framework/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.props

Is there an official up-to-date reference somewhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per this [file](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/docs/SharedFramework.md) in the source code:

> The contents of the shared framework are defined in two ways:
>
> - [eng/SharedFramework.Local.props](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/eng/SharedFramework.Local.props) - this file is generated from the .csproj files in this repo by looking for projects which have set `<IsAspNetCoreApp>true</IsAspNetCoreApp>`.
> - [eng/SharedFramework.External.props](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/eng/SharedFramework.External.props) - this file lists all assemblies shipped in Microsoft.AspNetCore.App which are built by source code found in other repositories.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thx!